# How to use git rebase to squash commits around a merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

What would be the simplest way to rebase around a merge with git?

In one of my branches I've been playing around with a bunch of different things speculatively, with a large number of failed and partially failed attempts. Now that I have things working, I'd like to go back and squash a bunch of the guess-and-check commits, using interactive rebasing.

The complication is that during the process I merged in another branch. I want to keep that merged branch as-is (not re-writing any commits on it), and also keep the merge commit in the same relative place in my branch. (Because there's some before/after dependencies on the functionality in my branch.) I tried doing a straight `git rebase -i`, but the branch I merged in has a fair number of commits from the point at which I last diverged, and as they show up in the interactive rebase file, they make things complicated.

A diagram might help. What I have now:

```
#-#-#-#-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* My branch
 \                   /      
  #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-# The merged branch
```

What I want:

```
#-#-#-#-----*-------*-*----*------* My branch
 \                   /      
  #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-# The merged branch
```

("#" are commits I want to keep as the same, SHA1-wise, and the filesystem contents of the two merge commits should be identical.)

I haven't pushed any of the commits I want to rebase to a remote server. (Though the branch which I merged *is* on the remote server.)

Comment: Have a look [here](http://apasca.blogspot.sg/2012/02/git-rebasing-merge-commits.html).  You may have to manually redo the merge commit in the history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DavidN's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981105/1256452) is correct—remember that rebase is just *copying* commits—but a little tricky to execute.  You'll need to save two particular commit IDs and maybe even use another branch name.

I would actually do this with a new branch name and `git cherry-pick` and a new `git merge`, myself.  Here's the method, using your diagram, annotated slightly, and some actual Git commands.  You have:

> ```
> A-#-#-B-*-*-*-*-*-*-C-M-D-*-*-*-*-*-*-E My branch
>  \                   /      
>   #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-# The merged branch
> ```

You want:

> ```
> A-#-#-B-----*-------*-m----*------* My branch
>  \                   /      
>   #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-# The merged branch
> ```

You can start with:

```
git checkout -b rebased B
```

which gets you a new branch name pointing to commit `B`.  Now you can:

```
git cherry-pick -n B..C
```

(or use raw IDs) to copy all the `*` commits after `B` up through and including `C`, then `git rebase -i B` and squash some to get your two `*` commits.

Now you're ready to merge; so `git merge M^2` to merge with commit `M`'s second-parent from `The merged branch`.  If that fails (or if you want to modify it, add `--no-commit` and now you are where it stopped), you can fix up the merge by checking files directly from commit `M`, assuming you want the same merge resolution you had there.

(If you have `git rerere` enabled, most of this happens mostly automatically at this point.)

Once you commit, or the merge is done, you have the ID of the new merge commit `m`.

Now you're ready to cherry-pick commits `D` through `E` inclusive, so:

```
git cherry-pick D^..E
```

(we need `D^` here to get `D` included—or you can use the raw SHA-1 ID of commit `M`, the original merge).  Then `git rebase -i m` to rebase just the new copies of `D`-through-`E`, without backing up past the new merge `m`.

When you are all done, you have the diagram you want.  The name of the branch is `rebased` rather than `My branch`,<sup>1</sup> though, and you have branch `My branch` pointing to commit `E`.  So `git checkout My branch` and then `git reset --hard rebased` to point the old name at the new branch-tip-commit, after which you can delete the name `rebased`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Obviously this is not the actual name, since having a space in a branch-name is bad.

Comment: plus one for you torek because you actually took the time to write out the whole explanation.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you prefer to cherry-pick instead of using the --onto option?

Comment: It just seems more straightforward for this particular case. We need to copy two sets of commits, with one merge in the middle.  While `git rebase -i -p` would probably do the right thing, the documentation warns that it (`rebase -p`) is squirrelly about editing the commit list when there's a merge in the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the manual approach and just do an interactive rebase on MyBranch between the first branch commit from MyBranch to TheMergedBranch to squash down your stuff. Then merge in TheMergedBranch. Then do an interactive rebase --onto your new branch with the upstream and commit picked from the original MyBranch to get those.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use rebase for this, use grafts.  Remember that commits are full-content snapshots, the commits you want as a result are content-identical with existing commits, you just want to rewire the parentage.  That's what grafts are for.

First, do this in a sandbox repo so you can just abandon and wipe it if you don't like what's happening:

```
git clone -s . "${other=`mktemp -dt`}"
cd "$other"
```

Set up the parentage you want

```
echo > .git/info/grafts $(git rev-parse M B M^2)
echo >>.git/info/grafts $(git rev-parse E M)
```

(I think you've got one or two more commits you want in there, just list the commits you really want for parents in place of the ones you've got, git's revision walking will follow your lead)

Then

```
git filter-branch -- --all
```

and if you like the results push them back.

Comment: Grafts? I haven't ever heard about grafts -- do you have a link to a good explanation?

Comment: grafts are repo-local ancestry overrides. Anything in git that sees ancestry sees the grafted ancestry, in particular things that rewrite commits see it and so bake it into the rewritten commits.  There's nothing more to them than that.  You use them any time you wish the history in your repo had different ancestry structure than it has at the moment.